# How to improve query with two contexts - MVC5, LINQ n EF

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two contexts. In one of them i have two views of which i get cods related to an entity from the another context. This query is taking too long time. How to improve it?

```
        var negociacoes = _db.Negociacoes.Include(o=> o.User).ToArray();
        var produtos = _oriDb.Vw_Produtos.ToArray();
        var clientesVendedor = _oriDb.Vw_ClientesVendedores.ToArray();


        var query = from n in negociacoes
                    join p in produtos on n.ProdutoId equals p.ProdutoId
                    join c in clientesVendedor on n.ClienteId equals c.codigo_entidade


                    select new NegociacaoView
                    {
                        NegociacaoId = n.NegociacaoId,
                        ProdutoId = n.ProdutoId,
                        Produto = p.descricao,
                        ClienteId = n.ClienteId,
                        Cliente = c.razao_social,
                        Rca = n.Rca,
                        Quantidade = n.Quantidade,
                        Preco = n.Preco,
                        Situacao = n.Situacao,
                        UserId = n.User.UserName,
                        Atendente = n.Atendente,
                        CondicaoId = n.CondicaoId,
                        DataCriacao = n.DataCriacao,
                        DataLiberacao = n.DataLiberacao,
                        Observacao = n.Observacao,
                        User = n.User
                    };


        return query.ToList();
```

Comment: The whole tables get fetched from db for `negaociacoes`, `produtos` and `clientesVendedor`, so you might want to use a timer to see if that's the problem. The last query isn't that complicated, so if that query turns out to be the problem it's likely more a problem with your db structure than with the query itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to speed this up:

- It helps to run the smallest most efficient query first, then use those results to constrain the following queries.
- Defining a select list so the database doesn't have to materialize every column will speed things up and use less memory.

Unfortunately, no matter how you do it in LINQ, you will end up with sql that uses large IN statements. A sproc would give you access to temp tables and joins that would be even better.

```
    var negociacoes = _db.Negociacoes.Include(o=> o.User).ToArray();
    //Use results of first query to constrain the second two. You could maybe combine the second two into one query.
    var clientIds = negociacoes.Select(x => x.ClienteId);
    var productIds = negociacoes.Select(x => x.ProdutoId);
    var produtos = _oriDb.Vw_Produtos
        .Where(x => productIds.Contains(x.ProdutoId))
        //add a select. You're only using two columns from this table.
        //.Select(x => new { })
        .ToArray();
    var clientesVendedor = _oriDb.Vw_ClientesVendedores
        .Where(x => clientIds.Contains(x.codigo_entidade))
        //add a select. You're only using two columns from this table.
        //.Select(x => new { })
        .ToArray();

    var query = from n in negociacoes
                join p in produtos on n.ProdutoId equals p.ProdutoId
                join c in clientesVendedor on n.ClienteId equals c.codigo_entidade


                select new NegociacaoView
                {
                    NegociacaoId = n.NegociacaoId,
                    ProdutoId = n.ProdutoId,
                    Produto = p.descricao,
                    ClienteId = n.ClienteId,
                    Cliente = c.razao_social,
                    Rca = n.Rca,
                    Quantidade = n.Quantidade,
                    Preco = n.Preco,
                    Situacao = n.Situacao,
                    UserId = n.User.UserName,
                    Atendente = n.Atendente,
                    CondicaoId = n.CondicaoId,
                    DataCriacao = n.DataCriacao,
                    DataLiberacao = n.DataLiberacao,
                    Observacao = n.Observacao,
                    User = n.User
                };


    return query.ToList();
```